# SQL for finding multiple column matches (dups)

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm trying to write a query to find all rows that have three columns in common with other rows.  Imagine a person can only send one letter to another per day and I need to identify "dups" even though all of the columns may not be the same.

I want to see all rows that have the same **Sender_ID** AND **Recipient_ID** AND **SendDate** in common with at least one other row.

```
SELECT
Sender_ID, Recipient_ID, SendDate
FROM
Letter_Info
WHERE
??????
```

Is this a nightmare to write or am I just missing the simple solution?

Comment: Add your sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Sender_ID, Recipient_ID, SendDate
FROM Letter_Info
GROUP BY Sender_ID, Recipient_ID, SendDate
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: This returns a result but I only get those three columns displayed without seeing how many occurences there are.  It does get me specific examples that I can follow up with another query.

'SELECT *
from Letter_Info
where Sender_ID = <from query above>
AND Recipient_ID = <from query above>
AND SendDate = <from query above>;'

Comment: Thanks for solving this for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Sender_ID, Recipient_ID, SendDate, COUNT(*)
FROM Letter_Info
GROUP BY Sender_ID, Recipient_ID, SendDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I get an error with this solution.  It's related to attempted to group rows with columns that are different.  It work if I replace the select with just the columns I'm grouping by but that doesn't show me how many there are or the adjacent values.